# the executing order in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

For the simple html and js code snippet, the action differ from firefox and chrome.

The simple html and js code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <head>
        <title>test welcome</title>
        <script>
            document.write("welcome1")
            alert("welcome2")
        </script>
        <body>
            <h3>welcome3</h3>
        </body>
    </head>    
</body>
</html>
```

1.Open it with firefox.

[image]

To click the `ok` in alert.

[image]

The executing order is : welcome1 ,welcome2,welcome3.

2.Open it with chrome.

[image]

To click the `ok` in alert.

[image]

The executing order is : welcome2 ,welcome1,welcome3.

Why chrome parse the simple html and js code that way?
How to make chrome behave such the same way as firefox do?

Comment: The "execution order" is the same, the only difference is that Chrome's renderer defers the actual rendering. This makes no difference to the Javascript environment.

Answer (score 0):

All browsers will stop execution when an alert is encountered, however, Firefox will not halt rendering for alerts. This is primarily due to the vagueness of the standard, ECMA, who writes the ECMAscript standard (upon which Javascript is built) does not mention `window.alert()`, as it is specific to Javascript, meaning browsers are free to implement it however they like, and they do.

You can force the popup to occur after page load with something like this `<body onload="window.alert('Hello World')">`, or using the `defer` attribute.